# regex c# expression to validate all numbers except zero

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am working Web API where I need to validate data so I am using regex for that.
In web I have a field where It masking is there for that field that only negative numbers upto 4 digits.
So for same I have put regex in API as below :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^-\d{0,4}$", ErrorMessage = "The cond_ab field must be negative number and maximum length is 4")]
```

But its failing for case when I pass 0, then its giving validation message. So i need regex to validate number that it must be negative and upto to maximum 4 digits but don't it should pass if number is 0

Comment: So you want a non-zero digit followed by 0 to 3 more digits which might be zero?  Or do you want to allow leading zeros such as `-0034` ?

Comment: Your current expression also accepts only `-`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen 0 should be accepted that what I am trying to achieve along with validation.. right now if I send 0, its throwing validation message.. so I want 0 to be accepted

Comment: Your current regex forces a `-`. Try `-0`. That schould be accepted.

Comment: @Verarind yes I know that but that is what I want to avoid. So only sending 0 should also work

Comment: @Mahajan344 Sorry, misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this expression to accept zero (`0`) or any negative number up to 4 digits:

```
@"^(0|-[1-9]\d{0,3})$"
```

If you also want to accept `-0`, `-0123` and the likes, you can use:

```
@"^(0|-\d{1,4})$"
```

Comment: I am still getting validation message , if I send field value as 0

Comment: @Mahajan344 Updated my answer

Comment: Please use `^(0|-[1-9]\d{0,3})$` because I'm pretty sure that `-0` should not match. Btw: only `-` might also be avoided.

Comment: @Verarind How do you know? `-0` is numerically equivalent to `0`, so why shouldn't it?

Comment: Hm. ... okay. Maybe. But I'm still of the opinion that `-` should not match.

Comment: @Verarind as suggested by Robby , @"^(0|-\d{0,4})$" , it also accepts -0 :)

Comment: @Mahajan344 Yeah, but it also accepts the bare `-`. I you want to accept `-0`, it should be: `@"^(0|-\d{1,4})$"`

Answer (score -2):

Use this expression . 
If you pass -12 then it will work if you pass -012 then give error .

^-[1-9]\d{0,4}(.\d*)?$

Comment: That will also work for positive numbers and it should not.